# c++ printing the complete square numbers in an array

Tags: c++

How can i print all complete square numbers available in the array

this is my array:

```
int main()
{

int array[6];

cout<<"Enter 6 #'s: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    cin>>array[i];
}
```

Comment: Whats is a complete square number?  Some example output and input will help.

Comment: @NathanOliver complete square numbers (e.g. 4, 9, 16, 25 etc.)

Comment: You don't need an array for this problem, so removing that, it appears your issue is not writing the code to determine whether *a* number is square or not. If you think we're writing that for you, think again.

Comment: Multiply each number in the array by itself and you'll get a square.

Comment: So a number that has a integer square root.  So what part of finding this do you not know how to solve?  Think about how would you do it on pencil and paper and try and translate that into code.

Comment: Maybe you should reformat the question. It's not clear whether you need to find the squares **in** the provided numbers or find the squares **for** the provided numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm:

```
For each slot in the array do:
  if value in the slot is complete square number, print it.
```

The difficult part is determining a perfect square.
Hint:  use `sqrt` (square root) function.